# No virtual method at(Ljava/lang/Object;I)Landroidx/compose/animation/core/KeyframesSpec$KeyframeEntity

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am getting the following error on CircularProgressIndicator after upgrading to compose bom `2024.01.00` from `2023.10.01`. What am I doing wrong?

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method at(Ljava/lang/Object;I)Landroidx/compose/animation/core/KeyframesSpec$KeyframeEntity; in class Landroidx/compose/animation/core/KeyframesSpec$KeyframesSpecConfig; or its super classes (declaration of 'androidx.compose.animation.core.KeyframesSpec$KeyframesSpecConfig' appears in /data/app/~~UsXlPxBRrCk6Kgqqdu5UvA==/me.jerryokafor.ihenkiri.debug-c4yfK-gLz9ZQ8fKqIz3WEw==/base.apk)
  at androidx.compose.material3.ProgressIndicatorKt$CircularProgressIndicator$endAngle$1.invoke(ProgressIndicator.kt:371)
  at androidx.compose.material3.ProgressIndicatorKt$CircularProgressIndicator$endAngle$1.invoke(ProgressIndicator.kt:369)
  at androidx.compose.animation.core.AnimationSpecKt.keyframes(AnimationSpec.kt:649)
  at androidx.compose.material3.ProgressIndicatorKt.CircularProgressIndicator-LxG7B9w(ProgressIndicator.kt:369)
  at me.jerryokafor.feature.movies.screen.MoviesScreenKt$MoviesScreen$3.invoke(MoviesScreen.kt:275)
  at me.jerryokafor.feature.movies.screen.MoviesScreenKt$MoviesScreen$3.invoke(MoviesScreen.kt:178)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
  at me.jerryokafor.core.ui.components.BackgroundKt.Background(Background.kt:69)
  at me.jerryokafor.feature.movies.screen.MoviesScreenKt.MoviesScreen(MoviesScreen.kt:178)
  at me.jerryokafor.feature.movies.screen.MoviesScreenKt.MoviesScreen(MoviesScreen.kt:139)
  at me.jerryokafor.feature.movies.navigation.MoviesScreenKt$moviesScreen$1.invoke(MoviesScreen.kt:58)
  at me.jerryokafor.feature.movies.navigation.MoviesScreenKt$moviesScreen$1.invoke(MoviesScreen.kt:57)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:139)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
  at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$14$1.invoke(NavHost.kt:308)
  at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$14$1.invoke(NavHost.kt:306)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:248)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.saveable.SaveableStateHolderImpl.SaveableStateProvider(SaveableStateHolder.kt:84)
  at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt.SaveableStateProvider(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:65)
  at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt.access$SaveableStateProvider(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:1)
  at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt$LocalOwnersProvider$1.invoke(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:52)
  at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt$LocalOwnersProvider$1.invoke(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:51)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
  at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt.LocalOwnersProvider(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:47)
  at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$14.invoke(NavHost.kt:306)
  at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$14.invoke(NavHost.kt:295)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:139)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
  at androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedContentKt$AnimatedContent$6$1$5.invoke(AnimatedContent.kt:755)
  at androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedContentKt$AnimatedContent$6$1$5.invoke(AnimatedContent.kt:744)
```

Comment: There is a [bug ticket](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/322214617) in Google Issue Tracker.

Answer (score 22):

I just experienced the same thing. The version `1.1.2` included in the BOM for `androidx.compose.material3:material3` seems broken.

I updated the specific dependency for `material3` to `1.2.0-rc01` while keeping the rest of the versions from the BOM until they release the next version which hopefully will fix this.

Update: this is fixed in the BOM `2024.02.00`

Comment: Yep, this works, and there is a deprecation at least for LInearProgressIndicator, they say one should use the overload that takes a lambda

Comment: BOM version `2024.02.01` fixes the error.

Comment: I'm experiencing this issue as well but upgrading to the latest BOM doesn't fix it.

Answer (score 4):

This issue is already tracked, you can check here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/322214617

CircularProgressIndicator works fine if you define material3 lib version 1.2.0-rc01 like this

```
implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3-android:1.2.0-rc01")
```

It is a temporary solution until they release a new compose BOM version with material3-android:1.2.0-rc01 included

Answer (score 2):

The new Compose BOM seems to have broken Material 3 lib replace the following to resolve it for now

in libs.version.toml

```
[versions]    
material3 = "1.2.0-rc01"
[libraries]
androidx-material3 = { group = "androidx.compose.material3", name = "material3", version.ref = "material3" }
```

if you are not using toml then add this in your gradle file

```
implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.2.0-rc01")
```

Answer (score 2):

This issue is fixed in latest compose-bom. Just upgrade compose-bom to `2024.02.00` and compose libraries to version `1.6.1`.

Answer (score 1):

I also updated my project to the ***Compiler 1.5.8*** latest version but I was also facing this error. Basically, We are encountering this issue due to the CircularProgressIndicator(). To Resolve this issue, We simply need to add the progress inside the CircularProgressIndicator.

**Before:**

```
CircularProgressIndicator()
```

**After:**

```
CircularProgressIndicator(
      progress = 0.89f,
  )
```

By this way, Issue is resolved.
But still if you don't want to pass the hard coded progress value then use the Material 3 dependency with latest version.

Comment: But I want an indeterminate circular progress indicator, not a determinate one.

Comment: Then you need to use the Material 3 dependency with the latest version like:
`androidx.compose.material3:1.2.0-rc01:`

Comment: Worked for me with Material 2